# What does 'additive framework' mean?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, gamlss

What does it signify in the context of non-linear relationships between multiple explanatory variables and dependent variable?

Just looking for an intuitive explanation.

In the context of GAMLSS framework.